# SQL merge two rows in one

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server 2005. I was trying to merge two rows in one.

Need help to exclude the Identity number and ApprovalCode NULL value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                  WHEN (CONVERT(varchar(12), t1.referenceInfo)) like '1000%' THEN
                   (+ '"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), t1.referenceInfo)) + '"'
                  ELSE
                   '0'
                END AS [ identity number ],
                CASE
                  WHEN LEN(ISNUMERIC(CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo))) < 12 THEN
                   (+ '"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo)) + '"'
                  WHEN (CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo)) LIKE '10%' THEN
                   (+ '"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo)) + '"'  
                  ELSE
                   '0'
                END AS approvalcode
  FROM dbo.GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST t1
 INNER JOIN dbo.GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST t2
    ON t1.guestCheckID = t2.guestCheckID
 WHERE t1.guestCheckID = 78362401
   AND (t1.referenceInfo) LIKE '1000%'
  and (t2.referenceInfo) NOT LIKE '1000%'
  --AND LEN(ISNUMERIC(CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo))) < 12 
 GROUP BY t1.referenceInfo, t2.referenceInfo
```

reference table as below
http://postimg.org/image/45q41bogf/

I wanted to park the value which like 10000% in identity number and park the value which less than 12 digits in approval code. If approval code has less than 12 digits then null.

Appreciate if can help me out on this

Result
http://postimg.org/image/ngr9yzb6z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                  WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(12), t1.referenceInfo)) > 11 THEN
                   (+ '"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), t1.referenceInfo)) + '"'
                  WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo)) > 11 THEN
                   (+ '"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo)) + '"'
                  ELSE
                   '0'
                END AS [ identity number ],
                CASE
                  WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(12), t1.referenceInfo)) < 12 THEN
                   (+ '"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), t1.referenceInfo)) + '"'
                  WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo)) < 12 THEN
                   (+ '"') + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(12), t2.referenceInfo)) + '"'
                  ELSE
                   '0'
                END AS approvalcode
  FROM dbo.GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST t1
 INNER JOIN dbo.GUEST_CHECK_LINE_ITEM_HIST t2
    ON t1.guestCheckID = t2.guestCheckID
 WHERE t1.guestCheckID = 78362401
   AND t2.referenceInfo is not null
   and t1.referenceInfo is not null
 GROUP BY t1.referenceInfo, t2.referenceInfo
```

Note that I changed 2 lines of your where clause. It looks like you used "<> 0" where you may have meant to use "is not null".

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
HAVING [identity number] is not null and approvalcode is not null
```

at the end..

Comment: I have edited the question. Please help guys. I needed all digit start with 1000XXX in identity field, and start with 10XXXX in approval code. and there is no any digit start with 10 return null in approval code.